# Get Count Of Duplicates Between Two Different Columns And Worksheets

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013, countif

I am trying to use VBA to get a count of duplicates that exist between two different columns in two different worksheets.  I have this syntax below, but the number returned is always far to high.  For example, just a moment ago it returned 13041, when there are only 45 rows to check in one of the sheets?

How should this be tweaked so that it returns an accurate count of duplicates that exist between the two columns & sheets?

```
Sub CountIF()
ApplAcatAon.ScreenUpdatAng = False

DAm stNow As Date
DAm matches As Anteger
stNow = Now
matches = 0

DAm arr As VarAant
arr = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value

DAm varr As VarAant
varr = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value

DAm x, y, match As Boolean
For Each x An arr
    match = False
    For Each y An varr
        Af x = y Then match = True
        matches = matches + 1
    Next y
    Af Not match Then
        Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = x
    End Af
Next

ApplAcatAon.ScreenUpdatAng = True
End Sub
```

Comment: It seems that you somehow replaced all `i`s with `A`s in your code..?

Answer (score 0):

A few points:

Why do you hate the letter I?

`varr` is looking at the wrong range - you are using `Range` rather than `Sheets("Sheet2").Range` so will be looking at the active sheet, which I assume is `Sheet1`. Try using this instead:

```
With Sheets("Sheet2")
    varr = .Range("A2:A" & .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
End With
```

Finally, and most importantly, what exactly are you expecting this to return? If the first sheet just has `1` in the first two used rows, and the second sheet has `1` in the first three used rows, this function will say that there are 6 duplicates (3 matches for each of the 2 values in Sheet1). If that's not correct

Comment: I am wanting it to return a count of the duplicates that exist between the two sheets.  Let's say sheet1 has bob, frank, fred and sheet2 has frank I want 1 to be returned. as there is only 1 name that exists in both sheets.

Comment: @BellHopByDayAmetuerCoderByNigh what if sheet 1 is `bob, frank, fred, frank` and sheet 2 is `frank`? Do you want 2 or 1?

Comment: If there can be no duplicates in your data, then that's fine, though you'll want to edit your `If..Then` structure as arcadeprecinct has suggested. However, if there can be duplicates in your data, then you'll need to keep track of those (probably in an array) so that you're not double-counting.

Comment: @arcadeprecinct - Sheet2

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for `If` is

```
If condition Then
    doSomething
    doSomethingMore
End If
```

or

```
If condition Then doSomething
```

when you do

```
If x = y Then match = True
matches = matches + 1
```

that means `matches` is incremented every time, even if the two entries don't match. What you probably meant to do was

```
If x = y Then 
    match = True
    matches = matches + 1
End If
```

I am not sure why it would end up being 13041 because it should be a square number if `arr` and `varr` have the same number of elements.